# Saving values from checkboxes in my db

Tags: php, database, checkbox

I am trying to store the values from checkboxes inside my database. So far, I was only able to store the last checkbox choice. Afterwards, I tried following someone's example, but I got so confused. How could I ensure that all my data is being stored inside the database?

In my table, my column which I want to contain the information is named "categories". As for the rest, it is below (2 of them only)

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="categories" value="categories">Categories</td>       

        <td>
            <div class="checkbox";>
                <label class="checkbox_label">
                    <input name="cats" value="Accessoires" type="checkbox" class="checkbox1"/>
                    Accessoires
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox";>
                <label class="checkbox_label">
                    <input name="cats" value="Mobilier de bureau " type="checkbox" class="checkbox1"/>
                    Mobilier de bureau 
                </label>
            </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is the code I tried following:

```
$box=$_POST['box'];
$ledlamps = $_POST['ledlamps'];

$str = $ledlamps . ": " . implode(", ", $box);
```

And so I ended up with this:

```
$cats = $_POST['cats'];
$categories=$_POST['categories'];

$str = $categories . ": " . implode(", ", $cats);
```

Comment: You have not really stated what your issue is.

Comment: My values do not properly save in my db. At first, I got it to save only one value. Now, it saves only the word "categories".

Answer (score 1):

I do not have sufficient privileges to add a comment to the previous answer attempt but what @Erman Belegu was saying is right, `cats[]` should do the trick. Here is the code.

**The HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="categories" value="categories">Categories</td>       

        <td>
            <div class="checkbox";>
                <label class="checkbox_label">
                    <input name="cats[]" value="Accessoires" type="checkbox" 
                      class="checkbox1"/>
                    Accessoires
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox";>
                <label class="checkbox_label">
                    <input name="cats[]" value="Mobilier de bureau " 
                        type="checkbox" class="checkbox1"/>
                    Mobilier de bureau 
                </label>
            </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
```

The only thing I added was the submit button so I could only do something in the php when submit is clicked, here is the same php code.

```
<?php

$cats = array();

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['cats']))
        {
            $cats = $_POST['cats'];
        }
        $categories= $_POST['categories'];

        $str = $categories . ": " . implode(", ", $cats);
        echo $str;
    }

?>
```

If you select something and click echo you will see categories: and whatever you selected.

Hope this helps or perhaps I did not get exactly what your problem was in the first place.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for extended it on example. I just write the place when he need to change. Vote Up for you!

Comment: Uhm, nothing actually echoes :/
I understand that $str has to do with a string (or so, this is what google was telling me).

Whenever I look inside my database, I only see the word "categories".

Comment: If no checkbox is selected, it echoes only categories, if you select one check box, it echoes category: value of checkbox checked, if you select both, it echoes categories: value of both checkboxes. Try it out here on my test server [link](http://mindhyve.net/tester.php) Try all the 3 cases, check one box, check no box, check both boxes and you have to hit submit to see the different echoed result

If your database is only showing categories, it means that the string you create is only categories: hence this is what appears in the db. Can you please show me your code so I could look through it

Comment: and then we could try and figure it out together.

Answer (score 0):

The name of input shoud be `name="cats[]"`. In these form you will get array of value that you checked.

Comment: Now, the word "categories" appears in my db. And I get the error message:

Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /***/****/*****/formulaires/processForm-test.php on line 38

Comment: Why you did that hidden input called "categories"? Why you need it?

Comment: Concerning your question, merely as a visual. 

Also, I posted something else above concerning what you and Shawn were talking about.